# JQuery create pop-up window for image, get size of an image by URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to use JQuery to create a pop-up window to contain an image. When a link is clicked, the window will show up. The size of the window will depend on the image size.

There are a few links. The a link target is "_new", so when the link is clicked, the jquery is:

```
jQuery('a[target^="_new"]').click(function () {

        return openWindow(this.href);
    });
```

Then the pop-up function will be:

```
function openWindow(url) {
      width = $("img[src$='" + url + "']").width;
      height= $("img[src$='" + url + "']").height;
     window.open(url , 'newwindow', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height);
}
```

When I debug I found the URL is correct. But I am unable to get the image element by its URL (then I couldn't get its width and height to style the pop-up window size). Anyone can help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The problem could be the lack of `()` after `.width` and `.height`. jQuery object does not have such properties, try this `$("img[src$='" + url + "']").width()` and `$("img[src$='" + url + "']").height()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can only calculate the width and height after the images are loaded on to your browser memory

To make it work you'll have to perform the calculations in a load event handler.

```
var img = $('<img src="'+ url +'"/>').load(function(){ 
  var width = this.width;
  var height = this.height;
});
```

Comment: When it runs to 'var img = $('<img src="'+ url +'"/>').load(function()', it says 'Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf''. It's weird, because I never call this method. I am using .net aspx page, is this the reason?